# Sass @use won't import in Vue Components

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs3

I am trying to import a variable from a `scss stylesheet` into a `vuejs component` but I am getting an error. Importing it with `@import` works fine but not with `@use`.

**`colors.scss`**:

```
$color-x: blue;
```

**`contact.vue`**:

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
@use "../../css/colors";

.btn {
  background: colors.$color-x;
}
</style>
```

Website throws this:

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable: "$color-x".
        on line 22 of resources/vue/sections/contact.vue
>>       background: $color-x;
   ------------------^

    at Object../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-12.use[1]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-12.use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-12.use[3]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/vue/sections/contact.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=60450740&scoped=true&lang=scss (app.js:28382)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:52481)
    at Module../node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-12.use[1]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-12.use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-12.use[3]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/vue/sections/contact.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=60450740&scoped=true&lang=scss (app.js:46766)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:52481)
    at Module../resources/vue/sections/contact.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=60450740&scoped=true&lang=scss (app.js:48663)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:52481)
    at Module../resources/vue/sections/contact.vue (app.js:47775)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:52481)
    at Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/vue/index.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js (app.js:25818)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:52481)
```

Comment: The error says `background: $color-x`, not `background: colors.$color-x;`

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes, and I don't know why. Node Manager shows it as the second in the terminal while browser console shows the former.

Comment: You likely have old code running. Rerun dev server and probably clean cache, https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#caching-and-parallelization